# Calculating a quality score of something based on attributes

Tags: object-oriented, php5, laravel

I'm willing to have a way to calculate a **quality score** of an object; in this case an **addressbook contact**.

I believe there are way better approaches to do this and I'd like to hear your references.

How can I calculate a *quality scoring* of an object based on its properties?

```
/**
 *
 * get Quality
 *
 * @return float Contact quality percentual score calculated from profile completion
 */
public function getQualityAttribute()
{
    $quality  = 0;
    $quality += isset($this->firstname) ? 1 : 0;
    $quality += isset($this->lastname) ? 1 : 0;
    $quality += isset($this->nin) ? 5 : 0;
    $quality += isset($this->birthdate) ? 2 : 0;
    $quality += isset($this->mobile) ? 4 : 0;
    $quality += isset($this->email) ? 4 : 0;
    $quality += isset($this->postal_address) ? 3 : 0;
    $total    = 20;
    return $quality/$total*100;
}
```

If you want to know the purpose of this method or further in the app, [you can find the code here](https://github.com/alariva/timegrid/blob/master/app/Models/Contact.php).

Comment: This code will be more readable and easy to maintain if you have create an array with properties and and scores:
```
$qualityScores = [ 
    'firstname' => 1,
    'lastname' => 1,
    ...
];
```

Then, you can use a foreach ($qualityScores as $property => $score) to loop over $this.

Comment: Like, would you post an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach sounds logically good, as it allows to determine how much the profile has been completed. There seems to exist a correlation between people completing their profile fully and giving interesting data in these. It also provides an incentive for completion.

A first iteration of improvement could be to decouple the data and the calculation operation.

First, define an array with a bunch of scores.

Then, loop on this array and compute it:

```
/**
 * Computes the quality of a contact, according profile completion
 *
 * @return float The score calculated from profile completion (between 0 and 1)
 */
public function getQualityAttribute()
{
    $propertiesScore = [
        'firstname' => 1, 
        'lastname' => 1,
        'nin' => 5,
        'birthdate' => 2,
        'mobile' => 4,
        'email' => 4,
        'postal_address' => 3,
    ];
    $totalScore = array_sum($propertiesScore);

    $qualityScore = 0;
    foreach ($propertiesScore as $property => $score)
    {            
        if (isset($this->$property))
        {
            $qualityScore += $score;
        }
    }

    return $qualityScore / $totalScore * 100;
}
```

This is a first naive approach to illustrate the method, but introduces something not desirable, `$this->$property`: this works, but it's not easy to parse by a static analyzer, as the type is not easy to determine. Normally, such code should be replaced by an array.

A more robust approach is so something like this:

```
    $qualityScore = 0;
    $instanceProperties = get_class_vars($this);
    foreach ($propertiesScore as $property => $score)
    {
        if (isset($instanceProperties[$property]))
        {
            $qualityScore += $score;
        }
    }
```

Then, we could see the properties score array is a preference. Laravel offers a config repository to store that.

Move this array to config/app.php or better, create a config/quality.php so you'll be able to put future settings too:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Quality score per user profiles
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows to balance the equation which determines the quality
    | score of a profile, according its level of completion.
    |
    | You can assign a weight (the greater the more important) to each property.
    |
    */

    'scores' => [
        'profile' => [
            'firstname' => 1, 
            'lastname' => 1,
            'nin' => 5,
            'birthdate' => 2,
            'mobile' => 4,
            'email' => 4,
            'postal_address' => 3,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Now you can access it from the getQualityAttribute method using `$propertiesScore = Config::get('quality.scores.profile');`. Don't forget to add `use Config;` at the top of your file to get this facade.

Finally, if 0 is never a valid answer, you could use empty instead of isset, so you avoid a bug if the property is "" instead of null (that would give score).

Comment: Thank! Seems pretty much of what I was looking for. I will try it and let you know the results.